# Containerd - Job Name on Windows 10/11

Tags: windows, containerd

When I run containerd on my Windows 11 box

```
ctr images pull mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2022-amd64
ctr.exe run mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2022-amd64  hello cmd  echo Hello World
```

and check where the process isolated cmd.exe belongs to I find with Process Explorer from SysInternals that
[image]

the job object is named Container_hello like the created container instance name. On Windows 10 it is a long gibberish guid like string which is much longer than a GUID. Is this a Windows 11 feature only or can I get the same behavior also for Windows 10 dev boxes? When I need to drill into containers I use hcsdiag which shows on Windows 11 due to this changed behavior

```
C:\Source\git>hcsdiag list 
hello
    Windows Server Container,   Running,                                     , containerd-shim-runhcs-v1.exe
```

the clear container name which is much more descriptive than a random number.